# Port open high for a few moments more often

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, onc-rpc

I have a dns server running bind without iptables configuration. Running some scanners with nmap, I found that no root in some high moments ports are open but soon close, and stay in that loop. When I walk with root these ports do not appear at any time.

Here is an output of nmap:

```
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
Scanned at 2016-09-10 01:04:48 UTC for 0s
Not shown: 64996 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
53/tcp    open  domain
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
52347/tcp open  unknown
```

And a moment later ...

```
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
Scanned at 2016-09-10 01:04:49 UTC for 1s
Not shown: 64994 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
53/tcp    open  domain
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
38248/tcp open  unknown
52347/tcp open  unknown
55806/tcp open  unknown
```

Output of netstat -ltnp

```
Conexões Internet Ativas (sem os servidores)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Endereço Local          Endereço Remoto         Estado      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       7209/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52347           0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       902/rpc.statd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       888/rpcbind     
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.X:53         0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       7209/named      
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XX.X:53         0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       7209/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       7209/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       935/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               OUÇA       1258/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::48323                :::*                    OUÇA       902/rpc.statd   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    OUÇA       888/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    OUÇA       935/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    OUÇA       1258/cupsd
```

My system is `Linux lDebian13 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What is it these ports? will bug? is a backdoor? how can I get information from them?